# Google Chrome: load a web page via a websocket request?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to force a running instance of Chrome to display
  new web pages via the remote-debugging port?

Specifically:

Start the browser as follows:

```
  chromium-browser --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=remote-profile
```

Establish a Websocket connection to `ws://localhost:9222`

Send the following JSON:

```
   {
     "id":1,
     "method": "Page.navigate",
     "params": {"url": "http://www.google.com"}
   }
```

Should the above cause the browser to navigate to google?

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution.
Adding this here in-case someone needs this in the future:

1) Get websocat from: https://github.com/vi/websocat

2)  Start chrome:

```
 chromium-browser --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=remote-profile
```

3)  Get the URL to the tab:

```
curl http://localhost:9222/json > /tmp/pages
TAB=`grep webSocketDebuggerUrl /tmp/pages | head -1`
URL=`echo $TAB | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e s/\"//g`
```

4) Push it into Chrome:

```
echo '{ "id":2, "method":"Page.navigate", "params":{"url": "http://www.royalanarchy.com"} }' \
| ./websocat -t - "$URL"
```